# Ld.exe has stopped working on install with Perl Strawberry

Tags: perl, module, installation, cmd, strawberry-perl

Trying to install a module(Devel::Declare) on a Strawberry setup I got an error window telling me "ld.exe has stopped working".

Here's the command I ran on the CMD:
    cpan Devel::Declare

You can see the output here:
http://www.textswell.com/read,4230519294302

I then tried to do a manual install, so I downloaded the .zip file, and ran perl Makefile.pl on it and it did it ok... but when I did make(well actually dmake but it's the same) it had an error and an error window popped up saying "ld.exe has stopped working". Here's the output:
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=greom

I appreciate you taking the time to read it and I hope somebody can help me out with this

Comment: That means that `ld` crashed. You could try upgrading mingw. If that doesn't help, you should probably see if they can help you.

Comment: Ok, I'll upgrade mingw and come back to you.. thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: I had no mingw installed(the ld.exe comes from Perl64) so I installed it, and it still gives me the error. What else can I do?

Comment: Strawberry Perl comes with mingw. It's the port of gcc you're using. Are you use the one you installed was being used when you retried? You could try copying the installed files over from a machine with the same version of Strawberry Perl if you can get someone else to compile it. As for finding out why ld is crashing, you'd need to fire up a debugger, I guess. As I previously suggested, maybe talking to the mingw folks will help.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didnt know that.. thanks. The SP I have is a reinstall... I had some problems installing a module, so I tried ActivePerl, but it still didn't work, so I reinstalled SP... I'll try repairing it or reinstalling it... I'll try copying the installed files from my brother's pc. Thank you very much! If all else fails, I'll contact the guys from mingw... thank you :)

Comment: Follow Up for someone who might be having this same issue: It seems that it was a bad install.... I had two installation files(same version) one smaller(40 mb) while the other one was larger(60 mb). I had installed the 40mb... as soon as I uninstalled and installed the 60mb I stopped having this problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem.  It was due to another compiler environment (MinGW-64) existing on my PATH environment variable.  "dmake" was getting called by "perl Makefile.PL" but the wrong link/loader (ld.exe) was getting invoked.  I moved the older compiler environment off the path and it worked well.